# How to send big image (2MB) multiple files from server to client with UDP python socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I want to transfer multiple images over UDP. I know it is possible using TCP, but I want it over UDP. Below is the code fragment I used. Is it possible to transfer bigger files over UDP? I manage to transfer small file sizes, but failed for large files. I appreciate any help or alternative way to do using UDP socket.

Client code receiving an image.

```
BUF_SIZE = 1024
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('localhost', port))
sock.settimeout(30)
def rcv_data(sock, num_packet_to_recv, file_size):
    bytes_rcvd = bytearray()
    f = open(download_dir , 'wb')
    print('Receiving packets will start')
    while num_packet_to_recv > 0:
        try:
           client_data, server_addr = sock.recvfrom(BUF_SIZE + 8)
           seq_num = client_b_data[-8:]
           img_data = client_data[:-8]
           num_packet_to_recv = num_packet_to_recv - 1
        #store img_data and seq_num to bytes_rcvd for later 
    #sorting by sequence number  
    f.write(sorted_bytes_rcvd)

    except Exception as e:
        print('rcv error {}'.format(e))
f.close()
```

Server side sending data

```
def send_img(host, port, file_name, num_pkt):
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.setblocking(0)
        sock.settimeout(60)
        client_addr = (host, port)
        # send the file name
        while num_pkt > 0:
            img_part = requested_file.read(BUF_SIZE + 8)
            sock.sendto(img_part + seq_num)
            num_pkt -= 1
```

Comment: With UDP, you will lose packets, and your application must take pains to request missing packets. TCP does that for you.

Comment: You will use a connection-oriented protocol to do this. Either you will create your own over UDP by writing a thousand lines of hopelessly buggy and complex code over months, or you will just use a vastly superior one known as TCP that you get in python by doing `sock = socket.socket()`. I've been on this site long enough to have a good guess about which one you'll choose.

Comment: James is correct that TCP will handle this problem for you 100 times better than anything you're likely to come up with on your own; but that doesn't mean that writing your own UDP-based file-transfer protocol isn't a worthwhile exercise ... if nothing else you will learn (through painful experience) all of the "gotchas" that a UDP-based protocol has to deal with (lost packets, packets received out-of-order, MTU sizes, fragmentation, bandwidth management, firewall issues, etc) and will have a newfound respect for TCP afterwards :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted code seems to assume that no packets will be dropped *en route* from the sender to the receiver -- that assumption doesn't hold up in real life (not even when sender and receiver are both located on the same machine!), which is the most likely reason your transfers don't work except on very small files (where you can sort-of-rely on luck to ensure that all the packets make it through on the first try).

To implement a more robust mechanism, your receiver program will need some way to (a) detect when a packet has been dropped, and (b) react to that knowledge by sending a message back to the sender requesting the sender to retransmit the data from the "lost" packet.  (And of course the retransmission-request-packet can also get dropped, so you'll need a way to handle that as well!)

Your sender program, meanwhile, will need to not only send the data  (as it currently does) but also receive any incoming retransmit-request-packets from the receiver, and react to them by retransmitting the requested data.

Depending on the exact design of your protocol, both sender and receiver may also need to take action after a certain amount of time has passed with no data sent or received, to avoid having the file-transfer process stall out if all the packets whose reception would have advanced it get dropped.

Therefore your current approach of just calling blocking `sendto()` or `recvfrom()` in a loop won't be sufficient; instead both sender and receiver will need to implement some kind of state-machine that allows them to both send the appropriate packet(s) at the appropriate time and quickly receive and handle any packets that come in.  This would typically be done either with separate sender and receiver threads, or alternatively by setting the socket to non-blocking mode and writing an event-loop around a blocking call to `select()` or `poll()`.  (I prefer the latter, because IMO while state machines are tricky to get right, multithreading is even trickier)

Placing a sequence number into each packet is a good start; that allows the receiver to know how to order the data, and allows it to detect when there is a "hole" in the data it has received.  Once it has detected a hole (i.e. one or more missing sequence numbers) it can send a packet back to the sender asking for those packets to be re-sent, and it will be up to the sender to react by re-sending those packets.  Repeat as necessary until the receiver has received a packet with every possible sequence number (you'll also need to communicate to the receiver somehow how many sequence numbers to expect).

Comment: Answer is correct in principle, but not advisable in practice. Inventing / implementing your own reliable transport protocol on top of UDP is much more difficult than it sounds and should not be taken lightly.  You are essentially re-inventing TCP or QUIC.  You are much better off using TCP or QUIC in the first place.